# Loading identity service through iframe

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, microservices

Loading identity service through iframe (ie) I have created a login page in identity service which is separate project and I have created a signup page in my client application, these are my two microservices. When I load localhost, it will redirect to signup page, when existing users try to login it will open a login page from identity service, this login page should load inside an iframe tag.

Comment: Is there a question? Also you need to show your code. Please read the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to implement sign-in with microservice-based architectures. I think the recommended one is to use token-based auth mechansims (for example JWT tokens). How you obtain your token can vary:

- use an API and write your own sign-in UI for it
- route to the UI of your auth provider and use a callback after sign-in to receive the token
- use pop-ups to receive the token

I think if you stick to the standards like Oauth2 or OpenID Connect you are good to go, no need to necessarily use an iframe.

Apart from that, you can use [micro-frontends](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/6-steps-to-your-angular-based-microfrontend-shell/) to pull multiple microservice UIs into a skeleton.

Comment: I have also tried in similar manner the problem im facing is , i have 2 projects one login page in identity service and other signup in my client application. i need to load login page in iframe from my client application

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which components are under your control and which ones are not?